# Typescript Initialize object member of class defined in the class

Tags: typescript, initialization

In a situation like this (simplified):

```
    class Order{
        items:{prices:number[],lastUpdate:Date};
    }
```

I want to have orders not undefined.

```
    class Order{
        items:{prices:number[],lastUpdate:Date} = {prices:[],lastUpdate:new Date};
    }
```

does it but I am not sure is the cleanest (lazy) way. What I don't want in this case is create an OrderItem class. Suggestions?

Comment: eeehm... what is the question? if you want an OrderItem without having orders undefined, could you instantiate it with constructor and creating it anywhere with `new Order(items: {[], new Date})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript will happily [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) types of variables and properties for you, and you only have to [correct it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) if it infers something you don't like.

So you could do this:

```
class Order {
  items = { prices: [], lastUpdate: new Date };
}
```

which infers `items` to be of type `{ prices: never[]; lastUpdate: Date; }`.  That's close to what you want but it has no idea that an empty array will hold numbers.  So you can then do this:

```
class Order {
  items = { prices: [] as number[], lastUpdate: new Date };
}
```

Now you've told it (via type assertion) that the empty array is for numbers, and `items` is inferred as `{ prices: number[]; lastUpdate: Date; }` as desired.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! (I think I'm getting a crush on typescript :-)